# JSON response Issues

Tags: json, coldfusion

I am using coldFusion inbuild `SerializeJSON` to get data from Array to JSON as below:

```
<cfset retData = '{"username":"#session.username#","items":#serializeJson(items)#}'>
```

This way in i am getting the response as:

```
{"username":"user1","items":["{\"s\": \"1\",\"f\": \"El\",\"m\": \"How are you\"}"]}
```

I tried removing the `backslashes` using the `jsStringFormat`, but no help..

tried it like this:

```
<cfset retData = '{"username":"#session.username#","items":#serializeJson(jsStringFormat(items))#}'>
```

But no help, can you guys point in right direction

Comment: Why the single quotes at all?

Comment: single quotes does not come up in redenered json, even json is valid, i tested on jsonlint.com

Answer (score 2):

Don't set it as a string. Make it a structure first, then call `serializeJSON()`. Based on the data, it seems `items` is already a structure.

```
<cfset refData = { 'username' = '#session.username#', 'items' = #items# } />
<cfset refData = serializeJSON( refData ) />
```

Comment: I tried, but Now i am getting an Error: `Message  Can't cast Complex Object Type Array to String
Detail  Use Built-In-Function "serialize(Array):String" to create a String from Array`. Items is a  `Array ` here

Comment: Do a `cfdump` of items and post screen shot to the question. From the output, it looks like `items` is an array with one element that contains a structure.

Comment: Also, show the code you used that is throwing this error. I ran this using `<cfset items = [{'s' = 1, 'f' = 'E1', 'm' = 'How Are you' } ] />` to create the variable `items` and the code I provided worked as expected.

Answer (score 0):

Use 'deserializeJson'.
It may help you.

```
<cfset items = '["{\"s\": \"1\",\"f\": \"El\",\"m\": \"How are you\"}"]'>
<cfset items = #deserializeJson(items)#>
<cfset retData = '{"username":"user1","items":#serializeJson(items)#}'>
<cfoutput >
    #retData#
</cfoutput>
```